# How to use another python project function into your project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm working with Django in a project, I want to use a python function from a project in Github, I can't install this project as a library with pip install dicom-exporter because it doesn' work.

The project I want to use:

> https://github.com/KitwareMedical/dicom-exporter/

the function I want to use :

```
dicom-exporter <path/to/dicom/folder> <path/to/output.vti>
```

The project contain `setup.py` file where there is script entry-point,

Please How can use this project in my django project.

Comment: The instructions on the page you linked tell you to do `pip install .`, presumably in the root of the downloaded files. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

**there is a simple way to do this in python**

1. make sure that the file you want to import your function from is in the same directory as your project
2. make sure that the file you are importing the function from isn't named like an already existing python module
3. you can import the function into your project by writing into your project:
   `from [name of the file that contains the function] import [name of the function you want to import]`

In this very case though you can simply type in your terminal `pip install .` as stated [here](https://github.com/KitwareMedical/dicom-exporter/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer, I did import the project into my project but I don't know how to import the function `from dicom-exporter import dicom-exporter` doesn't work

Comment: did you import the project throigh `pip install` or by downloading it and manually importing it?

Comment: by cloning the project into my Django project, then I did the `pip install .` as mentionned

Comment: then you should try downloading the project from the github page, put it in your project directory and then follow steps 1 through 3. If it doesn't work let me know

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Yes I idid put it in my project directory but I can't import the function, because there isn't a function (sorry I mentionned that aws a function), the whole folder project is like a script

Comment: @OussamaEddahri do you get any errors when doing `pip install . ` ? if yes add them to the question

Comment: Yes but I solved them, they were just some installation error for vtk and itk,

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple as the Readme file in the project says you would use pip install that ends with a dot. But you will need to open the where you downloaded the project, in its directory  contains the Setup.py in your command prompt in other to use the [pip install .], so make sure to download the project clone as a zip file and unzip in to the directory where you will find it in your command prompt and run the pip install .

```
#First navigate to where the project directory contains the setup.py file in your 
# command prompt and run pip install that ends with a dot 
 pip install .
```